No me muestra todas las etiquetas de mi grafico en el Reporting Services
Hola tengo un reporte donde me muestra una barra por mes, pero en las etiquetas no me muestra todos los meses, se salta meses, estoy buscando las propiedades pero no ubico la opcion o configuracion que este ocultando alguna etiqueta, alguno sabe el motivo ?


Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
